# Change margin size between row-fluid spans

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to change margins size between row-fluid spans.
I know that the margins are in %, so I need to set % in that way so it will be approximate 15px; in wide screens. I have changed margin-left to 1.8% via Firebug, it works, but when I load the site all spans go one after another.

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  margin-left: 2.127659574468085%;
  *margin-left: 2.074468085106383%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the margin between your spans in the Bootstrap .css by changing the @gridGutterWidth, @gridGutterWidth768, and @gridGutterWidth1200 setting(s) here: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html

Comment: I do not have gridGutterWidth, gridGutterWidth768, gridGutterWidth1200 in my bootstrap.css.

Comment: Exactly. You'd be creating a custom bootstrap.css with the form on http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html